# PHP Combine results from query into one string

Tags: php

I have a app that searches a database and retrieves 3 fields Name, Email Address, Year group.

I put these into a table and would like to have a mailto: link that has all the email addresses retrieved in it but seperated by commas..

something like this for example.

```
<a href=mailto:" .$row['Email'].  ">"  .$row['Email']. "</a>
```

and the link would actually look like this : mailto:john@yahoo.com,bob@gmail.com,kyle@microsoft.com

any ideas?

Comment: I'm terrible at SQL, but you could, instead of going row by row, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and then `echo implode(',',$arr['Email'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `join()` function.  For example:

```
$mailtolist = join(",",$queryresult);
```

Comment: Works too, join is an alias of implode.

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of emails then just implode the array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row()) {
    $emails[] = $row['Email'];
}

var_dump(implode(',', $emails));
```

Comment: Why not use `mysql_fetch_assoc`? Isn't that doing the same thing?

Comment: That'll work too... haven't used raw mysql* fetchers in a long time (pdo and orms). It's simply to demonstrate the idea of looping over rows, as he didn't actually include that piece of code in his OP.

Comment: Alright, thanks. SQL is one of those things I've been putting off and I'm trying to collect some of the SO wisdom before I get started.

Comment: SQL is definitely an art unto itself, however it isn't overly complicated out of the gate.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $row['Email'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></a>
```

this syntax is clearer and echoes only the variable on the place you want instead the whole line where echoed.

Answer (score 0):

Just concat the email like this:

```
   // loop over the rows
   $rows = //  resultset
    for ($row in $rows) {
     $email = $row['email'] . ","
    }

   // trim last comma

    // create href
    $desc = "this is the link description"
    href = "<a href=\"mailto:$email\">$desc</a>"

   // or
   <a href="mailto:<?= $email ?>">link description</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mike Purcell's answer, you can do this:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row) {
        $emails[] = $row['Email'];
    }
    $emailsString = implode(',', $emails);
?>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $emailsString ?>"><?php echo $emailsString ?></a>
```

Comment: mmm if i do that i get mailto:Array ?

Comment: It shouldn't do that. `implode` should return a string, not an array. Also, I was just using `mysql_fetch_row` because I was building on Mike Purcell's answer. You might not be getting your data from mysql, so just adapt it to what you're using.